# portrait video orientation issue in cropping video

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i'm working on video cropping. but when i crop and save it. it has saved incorrectly rotated into landscape. but it has done only in case of portrait video it's working fine with landscape video. i wanted to upload picture for your better understanding but it at least 10 reputation are required. unfortunately i have not.

but i have tried with AVMutableVideoComposition.

```
MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,nil];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = origionalComposition.frameDuration;
    MainCompositionInst.renderScale = 1.0;
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(nRenderWidth, nRenderHeight);
```

it doesn't work. i don't know how to manage. anybody know about please answer me i'm waiting for response. 
and i'm using AVAssetExportSession to save cropped video file.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    //exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
```

Answer (score -2):

**VAAssetTrak** have preferredTransform, this transform is used to rotate video to right position.

```
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* transformer = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:clipVideoTrack];
   CGAffineTransform videoTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        //portrait mode
        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height-translateX, -translateY);
        t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, M_PI_2);
        finalTransform = t2;
        [transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
        //portrait up side down
        t1 = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
        t2 = CGAffineTransformConcat(t1,CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translateX , -translateY));
        finalTransform = t2;
        [transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
        //landscape right
        t1 = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
        t2 = CGAffineTransformConcat(t1,CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-translateX , -translateY));
        finalTransform = t2;
        [transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }
    if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
        //landscape left
        t1 = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
        t2 = CGAffineTransformConcat(t1,CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-translateX , -translateY));
        finalTransform = t2;
        [transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    }

    //add the transformer layer instructions, then add to video composition
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transformer,nil];
```

[How to use](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

especially part with "//FIXING ORIENTATION//"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Bare link answers are generally disfavoured by the SO community. It would be nicer to edit your answer and explain the solution in your own words. However, providing the link as an amendment to that explanation would be ok.

Comment: And copying and pasting someone else's code into your answer is not acceptable either.